# Odoo: How to depend on a field from a different model

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14

I have a field two float fields I have added to the res.partner model. Now I have another completely different model that uses some parts of res.partner (i.e name, phone) but it doesn't inherit it. So what I would like to do is to update a field in my custom model anytime the two float fields I added in res.partner are updated. I tried using `@api.depends` but it doesn't seem to work with fields from a different model, although I have read otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `api.onchange`

```
partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Partners')

one_float = fields.Float('One Float', related='partner_id.one_field')
two_float = fields.Float('Two Float', related='partner_id.two_field')

@api.onchange('one_float', 'two_float')
def on_change_state(self):
    self.update_field = 'something'
```

Comment: I think the onchange decorator only works when a field is within a form view of a model. So it can't work in my case where I want like a more dynamic solution.

Comment: @ITJ How about ```@api.depends('one_float', 'two_float')```?